# Functions for setting cookies and outputting their IDs

Tags: php

Below are two functions.

The first is to set a cookie. This function is called on any product page on my website.

```
function setcookie() {

    $entry_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');

    if (isset($_COOKIE['recently_viewed'])) {

        $currentSession = unserialize($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']);

        if (!in_array($entry_id, $currentSession)) {

            if (count($currentSession) > 5) {
                unset($currentSession[0]);
            }

            $currentSession[] = $entry_id;

        } else {}

        $currentSession = serialize($currentSession);
        setcookie('recently_viewed', $currentSession, pow(2,31)-1, '/', '');

    } else {

        $recently_viewed[] = $entry_id;
        $currentSession = serialize($recently_viewed);
        setcookie('recently_viewed', $currentSession, pow(2,31)-1, '/', '');

    }

}
```

The second function retrieves the IDs in the cookie array and outputs them.

```
function recently_viewed() {

$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

if ( array_key_exists('recently_viewed', $_COOKIE) ) {
    $recent = unserialize($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']);
} else {        
    $recent = NULL;
}   

if ($recent) {
    $entry_ids = implode('|', $recent);
} else {
    $entry_ids = NULL;
}

$data['entry_ids'] = $entry_ids;

$variables = array();
$variables[] = $data;

return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($tagdata, $variables);

}
```

The code is built for the content management system Expression Engine. If you don't know 'codeigniter' code, just ignore those bits and take a look at the straight PHP if possible.

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to speed the functions up?

The first function, `setcookie`, is basically checking to see if a cookie exists.  If it does, it checks if the current `entry id` is in the array already.  If it's not, then it checks if there are more than 5 items in the array.  If there is, it deletes the first one and adds the new `entry id`. If no cookie exists, it creates a new cookie and adds the `entry id`.

The second function (recently viewed) is checks the cookie, converts it to a string with pipelines between `entry ids`, then outputs this string.

Comment: Why do you use cookies instead of sessions to store this data?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me tell you that I have zero experience with Codeigniter, but I suppose it is an MVC / OOP based framework, and I have plenty of experience with those. I am not trying to declare myself an expert or anything, just trying to be helpful and constructive. So here we go...

A few general words of advice:
 - try to avoid nesting control structures. **Work with early returns** in stead. You hardly ever need to nest an if inside an if, or even use an else. If you realy do, you are probably not **following the principles of single responsibility**
 - **don't waste resources** by storing stuff in variables and only using them once immediately after you stored them. Use the value you wanted to store directly.
 - **Put comments inside your code**. A lot of them! It may take a little bit longer now, but it will safe you time when you ever have to debug or alter your code!

With those hints in mind, I would write your first function as follows:

```
function setcookie() {  
    // prepare the entry id
    $entry_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');

    // if cookie has not been set before
    if (! isset($_COOKIE['recently_viewed'])) {
        // write the current entry id to a cookie
        setcookie('recently_viewed', serialize(array($entry_id)), pow(2,31)-1, '/', '');
        // and we are done (return self for chaining)
        return $this;
    }

    // convert the cookie to an array
    $currentSession = unserialize($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']);

    // if the current entry id is already in the cookie
    if (in_array($entry_id, $currentSession)) {
        // we are done (return self for chaining)
        return $this;
    }

    // if there are already 5 entries
    if (count($currentSession) > 5) {
        // shift of the first entry 
        // don't use an index here, cause there is no garantee the first element actualy has index 0
        array_shift($currentSession);
    }

    // push the current id onto the list
    $currentSession[] = $entry_id;
    // write it to a cookie
    setcookie('recently_viewed',serialize($currentSession), pow(2,31)-1, '/', '');
}
```

And the second function:

```
function recently_viewed() {
    // prepare the tagdata
    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    // if no recently_viewed cookie is present
    // (isset is supposed to be a little better in performance then array_key_exists)
    if (! isset($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']) ) {
        // do something and return the result
        return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables(
            $tagdata, 
            array(
                array('entry_ids' => null)
            )
        );
    }   

    // convert the recently viewed ids to a piped string
    // do something with it and return the result
    return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables(
        $tagdata, 
        array(
            array(
                'entry_ids' => implode('|', unserialize($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']))
            )
        )
    );
}
```

You could even put that function into a single 'line' of code, which should be a bit more performant, but a lot less readable. And imo you should always take readable code over performant code when the difference is small. Just as an example though:

```
function recently_viewed() {
    return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables(
        $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata,
        array(
            array(
                'entry_ids' => 
                    isset($_COOKIE['recently_viewed']) 
                    ? implode('|', unserialize($_COOKIE['recently_viewed'])) 
                    : null
            )
        )
    );
}
```